# How serious is the dent on alu frame?

Tags: frames, cyclocross, aluminum, accidents

I have crashed on my cyclocross bike and got a dent on it's alu frame. I don't see cracks. How serious is this dent? Can it lead frame to suddenly fail?
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

Comment: That poor Focus Mares. I have one as well, the frame seems so sturdy and over-engineered to me that I doubt such a little dent in such an uncritical area would cause any issues. On a sidenote: It’s amazing how resilient the power coating of the frame is.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the answer. I hope so, I think that is at least good that side profule edges (top, bottom, side) are not affected.

Comment: It could lead to failure 10 years down the road, but you'd see some cracks develop first.

Comment: My vote is it's OK. The dent is small compared to the diameter of the tube.

Comment: I'd think you're fine (I'm not convinced it was from a crash; you probably had it there, and noticed it after), but worth checking out the rest of the bike for damage.

Comment: Measure it accurately with calipers now, and repeat that periodically in the future.  Keep riding, but if things start changing then reevaluate.  You should visually inspect this damage every time you do a weekly/monthly safety/maintenance check.   Also look around both ends of the top and down tube for damage.  Pick up on cracks before they get big and bad.  Creaks are also a cause for concern.

Comment: I mark potential cracks (apparently only scratches so far) with permanent marker to see if they are getting worse.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the images correctly, that dent is in the upper tube of a diamond frame. This tube only has to withstand pressure, not tension. (When you have a frame failure, it's usually the lower tubes that fail, they are literally torn apart.) As such, I don't think that dent is critical. I'd be more worried if the dent were in the lower tube that connects the bottom bracket with the front.